# Facebook logInWithPublishPermissions return user with Read permission (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

I am logging with FB User permission

```
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
                permissions.add(list.add("email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_status");


LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();           
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, permissions);
```

My callback:

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                        (object, response) -> {
                                            handleSignInResult(response); //correct user
                                        });
                                ExtraUtils.putPreference(activity, Constants.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                                parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, name, email, gender, link");
                                request.setParameters(parameters);
                                request.executeAsync();
                            }...
```

I get correct loginResult with asked permission. And work with it in(execute newMeRequest)

After that, when i login with PublishPermissions:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_pages", "manage_pages"));
```

On new login screen, i don`s see any new additional permission. I get the same User response in my callback, without new permissions.Why is this happens? How can i get new user, or new Access token with publish permissions?

Comment: remove this line 
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

Comment: @Amizzar you set  addition permission on facebook developer console.

Comment: @Damini Mehra if i remove logout, logInWithPublishPermissions after logInWithReadPermissions throw runtime error. I won`t set addition permission on FB developers console. I think this is it. Thanks a lot

Comment: you have to take permission for access another permission from facebook